# Is a Unix list not supported in Dockerfile?

Tags: linux, dockerfile

I am changing the privileges on a few scripts before running them in the containers. I want to modify the script's permissions in one command.

This fails for the Dockerfile command:

```
RUN chmod +x {add, subtract}.sh
```

The following does work:

```sh
chmod +x *.sh
```

However, I do not want all the scripts in the local folder to have the execute permission.

**Edit:**

Here is the full Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.12
COPY . .
RUN chmod +x {add, subtract}.sh
```

Answer (score 3):

It fails not only because of docker, but because it is invalid sh syntax. For the shell syntax portion, you want:

```
chmod +x {add,subtract}.sh
```

Note the space is removed after the comma.

Furthermore, as per [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run), to allow for normal shell processing you need to modify the `RUN` command a little. To achieve what you want, do this:

```
RUN /bin/bash -c 'chmod +x /tmp/{add,subtract}.sh'
```

Tested with:

```
FROM golang:1.12
COPY add.sh /tmp
COPY subtract.sh /tmp
RUN /bin/bash -c 'chmod +x /tmp/{add,subtract}.sh'
```

Comment: I see, right now I have: FROM golang:1.12
So I just need to find something that works with golang1.12. Thanks

Comment: @NathanRosa , apologies, fixed answer to work. Also tested with golang.

Comment: Many lighter-weight Docker images don't include GNU bash, but only a smaller shell that implements [the POSIX shell spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18).  The `{word1,word2}` expansion isn't standard shell syntax.